# Simple Axios Function causing an ECONNRESET, unsure how to debug

Tags: node.js, axios, cheerio, econnreset

I am using axios and cheerio to scrape a site viewable through another computer on the same network's localhost. It's normally accessible through this machine via `https://<Machine on Network's IP>:<port>`

However, I get an ECONNRESET error with not a lot of code to debug, and no leads as to what on either end of the connection could cause the problem.

Specific IP/Port info hidden for privacy

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://XX.X.XX.XXX:####';

try {
axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

Running the code gives the following error:

```
Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:609:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1536:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  path: null,
  host: 'XX.X.XX.XXX',
  port: '####',
  localAddress: undefined,
  config: {
    url: 'https://XX.X.XX.XXX:####',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.2'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  request: Writable {
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: true,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      bufferedRequest: null,
      lastBufferedRequest: null,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      bufferedRequestCount: 0,
      corkedRequestsFree: [Object]
    },
    writable: true,
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      response: [Function: handleResponse],
      error: [Function: handleRequestError]
    },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _options: {
      protocol: 'https:',
      maxRedirects: 21,
      maxBodyLength: 10485760,
      path: '/',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: [Object],
      agent: undefined,
      agents: [Object],
      auth: undefined,
      hostname: 'XX.X.XX.XXX',
      port: '####',
      nativeProtocols: [Object],
      pathname: '/'
    },
    _redirectCount: 0,
    _redirects: [],
    _requestBodyLength: 0,
    _requestBodyBuffers: [],
    _onNativeResponse: [Function],
    _currentRequest: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.19.2\r\n' +
        'Host: XX.X.XX.XXX:####\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      _redirectable: [Circular],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    _currentUrl: 'https://XX.X.XX.XXX:####/',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function]
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem,

I used Dev Tools on Chrome to go to the Security Overview for the page I'm trying to access, the page was listed as having a "non-HTTPS secure origin"

Thus, I tried making the small change to my url (swapping http for https):

```
'http://XX.X.XX.XXX:####'
```

Got the response almost immediately

Simple, but glad I found it